# Problem in return value on objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

please look at this code:

```
-(NSString *) myfun:(NSString *)name paramnoone:(int)a paramnotwo:(int)b {
    static int numberofcall=0;
    if(a>b) {
        return name;
    }

    NSString *secondname = [[NSString alloc]init];
    secondname = [name StringByAppendingString:@"test"];
    numberofcall++;
    return secondname;
}
```

i have a problem on it, when my code is on "return secondname" next step is going to "return name" on if statement part, im confusing a lot , because c++ does not have this problem, 
please help me on solve it,
thanks for ur help and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: C++ and Objective-C, both having C as their ancestor, share the same logic statements. So I doubt you're running into a problem you can solve in C++ but not in Objective-C. Unfortunately your problem description is very confusing, I don't understand it. Please try to explain.

Comment: You are leaking memory when you do `secondname = [name StringByAppendingString:@"test"];` immediately after `NSString *secondname = [[NSString alloc]init];`. You are losing the original reference. As for the problem, does it return `name` even when `secondname` should be the return value?

Comment: Is it possible you're attempting to step debug an optimised build?

Comment: Are you stepping on a release (optimized) build? That would explain such behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Until the question is explained further I can't really answer the question, but still have valuable infos which justify being posted as an answer, so here it goes.)*

In the line:

```
NSString *secondname = [[NSString alloc]init];
```

You allocate an empty string. But in the very next line:

```
secondname = [name StringByAppendingString:@"test"];
```

You overwrite the pointer `secondname` to the previously allocated empty string, thus creating a memory leak. Since you do not use the empty string at all, remove the first line and turn the second line into:

```
NSString *secondname = [name StringByAppendingString:@"test"];
```

**Edit:** Based on comments to the questions, I think what you're asking is this (correct me if I'm wrong):

- You are *debugging* the method.
- While stepping through the method with the debugger, the flow proceeds normally through the method.
- But after the `numberofcall++;` line, the debugger suddenly jumps to the `return name;` instead of the `return secondname;` line.

If that's what's happening to you: this is normal behavior, unfortunately. When the debugger reaches a `return` statement the marker always "jumps" to the first `return` statement in the method. But even though it doesn't look that way, your `return secondname;` statement is really executed.

Comment: thanks man, my problem is that, if "if(a>b)" not happen  debugger go to "return secondname" after that go to "return name" in if stat, how can i fix this problem, i know my program have memory leak but its not only my problem.

Comment: Ignore that the debugger jumps from one `return` to the other, that's not what really happens, it's only what the UI is showing you. It's a bug in the debugger UI.

Comment: Thanks,I changed my function and spirited it to two part, its a very very bad bug.

Comment: @mahyar: It's annoying, but as I said: it's only a *visualisation* bug. The *code did run correctly*, the `return secondname;` was executed.